# How can I merge the result of 2 http calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I have 2 different webservices that I need to call. The first returns information about a city (id, name, state, population, and other statistics). The second service returns a list of hotels by city (hotel-name, city, state, and other info about the hotel).

I want to get the data from both services and merge them into one object array, I also need to match both calls by city and state.

I am not sure on the correct way to do this.

I tried to call each service separately and merge the data using the spread operator, but I could not figure out how to align the records in each result set.

I would like to know if I can use RXJS to do this kind of data merge.
I expect to have 1 object with all of the properties of both calls

Answer (score 2):

Use combineLatest

```
combineLatest(
  http.get('cityDetailsUrl'),
  http.get('hotelsInfoUrl')
).subscribe(([cityDetails, hotelsInfo]) => {
  You have access to city details and hotel info right here
});
```

The subscribe method will fire when both calls have finished.

Comment: Useful: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Comment: Better to use the interactive version of the marbles rather than a screen shot https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest

Comment: Oh yes, I *love* those!! Also, I've been using forkJoin for this sort of purpose, but I *always* forget about de-structuring assignment, which gives much more convenient names.

Comment: So much of RxJs suddenly clicked once I discovered RxMarbles.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally fetch the city first, when you get the result, use the information there to query the second service (e.g. use the `city` from the first service's response as parameter to initiate the second API request), pesudocode:

```js
fetch(`https://api.number.one?city=${yourcity}`)
    .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
        let result = json;
        // use result from first request to build the second one
        fetch(`https://api.number.two?city=${result.city}`)
            .then((data) => {
                return data.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                // here you extract the properties you need from the second API
                // and merge them with the $result variable from the first request above
                let obj = {
                    prop1: json.prop1,
                    prop2: json.prop2,
                };

                result = {
                    ...result,
                    obj
                };
            })
           .catch(err) => {

           });
    })
    .then((json) => {
    })
    .catch(err) => {

    });
```

it would of course be more elegant to abstract this into a few functions...

<strike>and no RxJS is about observables and doesn't do any kind of magic data-merging!</strike>

Comment: RxJs does lots of magic data merging. OP is using Angular and wouldn't be using fetch.

Comment: Re: "RxJs does lots of magic data merging", then I stand corrected, never used it for that purpose^^...don't like magic =D...A quick google turned up [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511) (which I'm gonna read as well...)

Re: Angular: As I wrote, this is pseudo code, meant to show the approach I might take conceptually in such a scenario